# Defer execution of directive until ng-options completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-chosen

I'm creating a select element in my Angular template with the following markup:

```
<select name="noOfPeople" ng-model="noOfPeople" ng-options="value for value in [] | range:12">
    <option value="">No of people*</option>
</select>
```

I want some custom styling and functionality added to this select element, and for that I'm using the [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) jQuery library.

To initialize the CHosen library on a select element I've written this directive:

```
directive('select', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            $(elm).chosen({disable_search: true});
        }
    }
})
```

This is working really well, and Chosen is now initialized on all of the `<select>` elements in my application. However this doesn't seem to work with using `ng-options` as the div's created by Chosen don't include any of the options generated by `ng-options`. If I look at the original `<select>` element in Chrome's developer tools though I can see the options are being generated.

My theory is that Chosen is being initialized on the `<select>` element before Angular has a chance to run `ng-options` and create the `<option>` elements in the DOM.

Is there a way I can defer the initialization of Chosen until Angular has finished its processing and added all of the `<option>` elements I want?

Comment: I think that the `priority` property on the directive can help you with this

Comment: I'd suggest you used an integration of Chosen with Angular, if at all possible. [This](https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen) may be a candidate.

Comment: Actually I just realized that using `priority` wouldn't address the underlying issue which is having to wait to initialize Chosen until after the options source object is available.  I think you should probably try @NikosParaskevopoulos suggestion first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject and use $timeout without a delay to put the action at the end of the browser event queue (after the rendering engine):

```
app.directive('select', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      $timeout(function() {
        $(elm).chosen({
          disable_search: true
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Note that this case is assuming the data for ngOptions is available at initialization and not retrieved asynchronously.